# In Visual Studio 2010, why does "Calculate Code Metrics" ignore .xaml.cs files?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010, why does "Calculate Code Metrics" ignore .xaml.cs files? Is there a way to include these sources in the calculation?

For example, the selected project below has many lines of code, all in .xaml.cs files:

[image]

### Update:

I follow what the two answers show from KodeKreachor and aKzenT, but I still get no lines of code. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option switch in the settings that disables code metrics for generated files. Try to turn that off.

**Source:** http://codemetricsviewer.wordpress.com/2011/06/26/how-to-get-results-for-code-behind-xaml-files/

**Edit:** It requires an extension to visual studio though, which you can get on the linked source. With this extension you get a new tool window where you can start an analysis. See also:

http://codemetricsviewer.wordpress.com/2011/06/26/where-can-i-find-the-code-metrics-viewer-in-visual-studio/

Comment: Tried this but still no lines of code; see my update for some details.

Comment: You have to start the analyzing from the new tool window you get. See the last link in the post I edited.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because there shouldn't be any code there but in your view models instead, :P 
Seriously though, these links should help you out:

Code metrics Viewer: http://codemetricsviewer.wordpress.com/2011/06/26/how-to-get-it-working/

Code metrics on xaml.cs files: http://codemetricsviewer.wordpress.com/2011/06/26/how-to-get-results-for-code-behind-xaml-files/

Comment: Yep, that's what the first link covers

Comment: Tried this but still no lines of code; see my update for some details.

Comment: Can you see the metrics if you run the extension? Here's a link that shows where it is: http://codemetricsviewer.wordpress.com/2011/06/26/where-can-i-find-the-code-metrics-viewer-in-visual-studio/